# Closure of complement

Tags: general-topology

This question is from Munkres topology: Section 17, exercise 8c:

Does $\overline{A-B}=\overline A-\overline B$ hold for any sets?

I have a solution that says that equality may not hold everywhere, because, $\overline A-\overline B=\overline{A-B}-\overline B$.

His proof to $\overline A-\overline B=\overline{A-B}-\overline B$ is

> $$\overline A-\overline B=(\overline{A-B}\cup\overline{A\cap B})-\overline B=\overline{A-B}-\overline B$$ for which I have used i) if $P\subset Q$ then $\overline P\subset\overline Q$ and ii) $\overline {P\cup Q}=\overline P\cup \overline Q$ .

I can't understand how we got $(\overline{A-B}\cup\overline{A\cap B})-\overline B=\overline{A-B}-\overline B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $\overline{A\cap B}\subset\overline B$ (which follows from the fact that $A\cap B\subset B$). It always happens that, if $X\supset Y$, then$$(Z\cup Y)\setminus X=Z\setminus X.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this awesome answer.